# MVC - Adding . at end of string in resource file makes it invisible

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application, I have put a string in my `CommonResourceFile` a string

```
* indicates mandatory fields.
```

I noticed a strange thing here. This string was not visible on the view. And on removing `.` from the end, it became visible. Why so?

**Update**

This is the related view code :

```
<span>*</span> <%:Html.Label(CommonResource.MandatoryFields)%></div>
```

**CommonResource.MandatoryFields** is **indicates mandatory fields.**

Comment: It looks like question missing sample of view code and/or resulting HTML. There is nothing special about dots in resource strings - I put plenty myself without any problems.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov : I don't think there is need of code here. Is it not the issue of resource file?

Comment: By 'not visible', do you mean the text does not show up in the generated html source? or is it just hidden?

Comment: The error is most probably in your view. Please post the relevant part of your view!

Comment: <div> in which I have placed the label having this string does not come in HTML. On removing . it comes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with resource files.

You are misusing the [Html.Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee310185%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) helper because it's argument **is a property expression** not the text that you want to display.

That's why it confuses when you have a dot `.` in your resource because it tries to interpret the input string as a property expression (so it's splitting on dots etc.).

So don't use the `Html.Label` to display arbitrary texts instead of write out the label tag by hand (or create an own helper)

```
<label><%: CommonResource.MandatoryFields ></label>
```